# PayPal responding with "CANNOT_MIX_CURRENCIES" when purchase unit currency changed

Tags: reactjs, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I'm selling an item which has a different price and currency depending on the delivery address.

If the user has two addresses, one in the US and another in the UK, they will be able to change the delivery address through PayPal. When the user changes the region from US to UK, PayPal informs my site that there has been a region change and it will reply with the new currency and price, changing from 345$ to £305.

When PayPal receives this update, PayPal displays an error to the customer. In the network tab there is more insight, and one can find the following error: `CANNOT_MIX_CURRENCIES`. However, both item prices and total prices are all converted to the desired currency, so there is no "mix" of currencies. Below is the request and the accompanying response that generates the error.

Request: PATCH -> [www.sandbox.paypal.com/smart/api/order/890595684S747592L/patch](http://www.sandbox.paypal.com/smart/api/order/890595684S747592L/patch)

```
{
    "data":{
        "patch":[
            {
                "op":"replace",
                "path":"/purchase_units/@reference_id=='xxx'",
                "value":{
                    "reference_id":"xxx",
                    "invoice_id":"xxx",
                    "custom_id":1,
                    "description":"xxx",
                    "amount":{
                        "currency_code":"GBP",
                        "value":"305.00",
                        "breakdown":{
                            "item_total":{
                                "currency_code":"GBP",
                                "value":"305.00"
                            },
                            "shipping":{
                                "currency_code":"GBP",
                                "value":"0.00"
                            },
                            "tax_total":{
                                "currency_code":"GBP",
                                "value":"0.00"
                            },
                            "discount":{
                                "currency_code":"GBP",
                                "value":"0.00"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "items":[
                        {
                            "name":"xxx",
                            "sku":"xxx",
                            "currency":"GBP",
                            "quantity":1,
                            "category":"PHYSICAL_GOODS",
                            "unit_amount":{
                                "currency_code":"GBP",
                                "value":"305.00"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }

}
```

Response:

```
{
  "ack":"contingency",
  "contingency":"UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY",
  "data": {
    "name":"UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY",
    "details":[{ 
      "location":"body",
      "issue":"CANNOT_MIX_CURRENCIES",
      "description":"CANNOT_MIX_CURRENCIES"
    }],
    "message":"The requested action could not be performed, semantically incorrect, or failed business validation.",
    "debug_id":"xxx",
    "links":[{
      "href":"https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#error-CANNOT_MIX_CURRENCIES",
      "rel":"information_link",
      "method":"GET"
    }]
  },
  "meta":{"calc":"xxx","rlog":"xxx"},
  "server":"xxx"
}
```

Below is the request (and response) for the creation of the purchase unit above.

Request: POST -> POST -> [www.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders](http://www.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders)

```
{
    "intent":"CAPTURE",
    "purchase_units":[
        {
            "reference_id":"xxx",
            "invoice_id":"xxx",
            "custom_id":1,
            "description":"xxx",
            "amount":{
                "currency_code":"USD",
                "value":"345.00",
                "breakdown":{
                    "item_total":{
                        "currency_code":"USD",
                        "value":"345.00"
                    },
                    "shipping":{
                        "currency_code":"USD",
                        "value":"0.00"
                    },
                    "tax_total":{
                        "currency_code":"USD",
                        "value":"0.00"
                    },
                    "discount":{
                        "currency_code":"USD",
                        "value":"0.00"
                    }
                }
            },
            "items":[
                {
                    "name":"xxx",
                    "sku":"xxx",
                    "currency":"USD",
                    "quantity":1,
                    "category":"PHYSICAL_GOODS",
                    "unit_amount":{
                        "currency_code":"USD",
                        "value":"345.00"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "application_context":{
        "shipping_preference":"GET_FROM_FILE"
    }
}
```

Response:

```
{
    "id":"xxx",
    "status":"CREATED",
    "links":[
        {
            "href":"https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/xxx",
            "rel":"self",
            "method":"GET"
        },
        {
            "href":"https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/checkoutnow?token=xxx",
            "rel":"approve",
            "method":"GET"
        },
        {
            "href":"https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/xxx",
            "rel":"update",
            "method":"PATCH"
        },
        {
            "href":"https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/xxx/capture",
            "rel":"capture",
            "method":"POST"
        }
    ]
}
```

I am using the [PayPal Orders API v2](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/), via the [react-paypal-button-v2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-paypal-button-v2) npm package.

The documentation for "CANNOT_MIX_CURRENCIES" mentions all currencies in the purchase unit must be the same, but it does not mention that a purchase unit currency change is not possible. Something confusing is that I could only find mention of this error ("CANNOT_MIX_CURRENCIES") in Billing Agreements API v1.

> CANNOT_MIX_CURRENCIES
>
> The currency code is not valid. All currency codes much match. Use same currency code for all amount objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `<script>` line where you're loading the SDK, currency defaults to USD, and this SDK line currency matters because it is used to determine which buttons can be shown before the orders v2 object is ever called.

If you need to change the currency after page load time, you can reload the SDK asynchronously.

```
function loadAsync(url, callback) {
    var s = document.createElement('script');
    s.setAttribute('src', url); s.onload = callback;
    document.head.insertBefore(s, document.head.firstElementChild);
}

// Usage:

loadAsync('https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=sb&currency=USD', function() {
  paypal.Buttons({
    createOrder: function(data, actions) {
        //your code here
    },
    onApprove: function(data, actions) {
        //your code here
    }
  }).render('body');  // Replace with selector to render in
});
```

Alternatively there is a node package, if you like dependencies more than 3 line functions :) https://github.com/paypal/paypal-js

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Only problem with this is that every time the currency changes, the session with paypal is reloaded, making the user have to click "Pay" again on our site. The currency is changing during the session with PayPal.

Comment: You should get that detail sorted out before sending the user to PayPal.

Comment: Apologies, that previous message wasn't very clear. The user can change their address (and therefore currency to pay in) on PayPal, so this detail cannot be sorted out before. I could label changes to addresses outside the pre-selected region as invalid, but I'd like to allow the user to make the change if possible.

Comment: Why does an address change necessitate a currency change? Anyway, the currency must be known before the buttons can be shown.

Comment: thanks, I think this just saved me a few hours debugging